# unable to redirect page using window.location in js

Tags: javascript, html

i want to redirect to home page using js function by its not redirecting to different page. getting error like this

> file:///D:/dotnetapp/@Url.Content( net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

```
 <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit" onclick="login()">Sign in</button>

<script>
    function login() {
        var userid = document.getElementById("Username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
         if (userid == "administrator" & password =="password")
         {
            window.location = "home.html";
        }
        else    
        {
            alert("username / password is incorrect");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are all of them located on the same directory?

Comment: `window.location.href`

Comment: yes all in same directory still not working .@wentjun

Answer (score 2):

If it is on the same directory level/relative, you can use this instead.

```
window.location.href = '/home.html';
// or window.location.href = 'home.html';
```

Just some additional information for your reference,

`window.location` is an object with various properties such as `href` and `hash`, whereas `window.location.href` is a string itself. Either ways, setting both `window.location` and `window.location.href` to a string value should lead to a redirection to another page.

Comment: An path starting with / is absolute to the root of the file system, it's not relative

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
window.location.href = "home.html"
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage) could be useful